# JSON API МойСклад. Запрос на получение шаблона Purchase Order меняет количество позиций Customer Order

Tags: мойсклад-api, moysklad-json-api

Баг JSON API

Можно воспроизвести если используя эндпоинт для создания шаблона **PurchaseOrder**

**PUT /entity/purchaseorder/new**

передать в теле запроса **CustomerOrder** с заполненными полями:

- **id**(существующим)
- **positions**(отличными от тех что есть в существующем документе)

То позиции в существующем в складе **CustomerOrder** изменятся на те что были переданы в запросе

Answer (score 2):

Если вам надо добавлять/удалять позиции документа, используйте API для работы с [позициями](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#header-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).